# Run Python package from files and not egg

Tags: python, python-packaging, python-egg-cache

I downloaded a Python package from Github.  To use it I had to install an python egg on my computer.  I'd like to make some modifications to the package.  To do so, I have to recompile the egg each time to test it.

My question is, how do I run the python files directly without having to recompile the egg each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an "editable" installation to link to the files directly, without having to build the egg each time.

```
$ pip install -e ./path/to/package
```

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs